# Why vscode's extension REST client can access my api?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I have a django application running in my server. In that application i use `django-cors-headers` to protect my api from other origins except the one i set by doing this:

```
# settings.py

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
   'http://localhost:3000'
]
```

When I tested it with other origins like `http://127.0.0.1:5500` it gave cors error and that's what i want.

BUT when i use vscode's extension called `REST Client` to access my api it worked without any errors.

How can i protect my api from that? I'm new to all these things so maybe there are things i dont know about. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CORS header doesn't prevent *access* to your API. It only tells *browsers* which cross-origin requests it should allow.

The only thing being able to access your API from the VS Code REST Client extension tells you, is that it doesn't respect the CORS header (and it shouldn't need to because it isn't a browser).

Comment: so how can i protect my api from that? so if someone knows my api then he can do what he want?

Comment: Usually you'll want to add [authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) to your API so that only users with a secret token or password will be able to access your API. If you want to restrict access to your API to certain IP addresses, you could either whitelist them in your load balancer (e.g. Nginx) or in Django (with a package like [this](https://pypi.org/project/django-ip-restriction/)).